# Place variable inside window.location.replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the jquery open a page with the url

```
search.php?city=cityname
```

Where cityname is the value which user selects from the input. This code always opens the following url,

```
search.php?city=cityname
```

For some reason, the cityname is not getting picked up.

```
<input id="city" placeholder="<?php echo $_GET['city'] ?>">
```

Here is the JavaScript.

```
<script>
$('#city').on('blur', function() {
    var cityname = $('#city').val;
    window.location.replace("search.php?city=cityname");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two errors

1. `val` function is not invoked, otherwise the function will be assigned to the `cityname` variable
2. The variable need to be concatenated with `+` operator

Code:

```
$('#city').on('blur', function () {
    var cityname = $('#city').val(); // Invoke the function here
    window.location.replace("search.php?city=" + cityname); // Concat the variable value here
});
```